# Call Procedure and add it to the sequence column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sequence, mariadb

i have a procedure in MYSQL (MariaDB) and this querying a Value from a table i.e. 99.

This is supposed to add as prefix to my auto increment column in table.

Let's say PREFIX(99) || Auto Increment value(15) = 9915.

Now I don't really know how to get this in a select query to MYSQL. I know from Oracle it is `Procedure||sequence.nextval`

Below is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`EventPanda`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GETDBID`(OUT DBID INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT settings_value INTO DBID FROM settings where setting_code='DB_PARAM';
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

And my auto increment column is:

```
table.sequence_id
```

Can someone help me to create a select script including the next value of the auto increment column?

Comment: Advice from an old-timer...  Yeah, that would be nifty.  But generally it is a "bad idea in the long run" to fabricate ids.

Comment: Why should this be a "bad" idea? Each instance has it's own prefix and this would prevent duplicates. Can you give me your thoughts?

Comment: One approach is 2 columns, concatenate later.  Another issue is when you change your mind about the 'numbering' scheme.